# How to check if there is a specific number in the database

Tags: java, jdbc

This is my entire code:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VerInformacaoPassageiro {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dbname = "BD22";
        String dbuser = "postgres";
        String password = "12345";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + dbname;

        try {
            BufferedReader in;
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
            System.out.print("Numero de identificacao: ");
            String identificacao = in.readLine();

            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbuser, password);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT nomeP, sexo, destinopretendido, dataviagem " +
                    "FROM passageiros " +
                    "WHERE nidentificacao='" + identificacao + "';";
            System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println( "Informacao do passageiro com numero de identificacao " + identificacao);
            System.out.println( "---------------------------------------");
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                int nidentificacaoP = rs.getInt("nidentificacao");
                String nome = rs.getString("nomeP");
                String sexo = rs.getString("sexo");
                String destinopretendido = rs.getString("destinopretendido");
                String dataviagem = rs.getString("dataviagem");
                if (nidentificacaoP == NULL)
                    System.out.print("Identificacao nao encontrada");
                else
                    System.out.println( nome + " do sexo "  + sexo + " para o destino " + destinopretendido + " no dia " + dataviagem );
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

But my doubt is in this part of the code:

```
    if (nidentificacaoP == NULL)
        System.out.print("Identificacao nao encontrada");
    else
        System.out.println( nome + " do sexo "  + sexo + " para o destino " + destinopretendido + " no dia " + dataviagem );
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
c.close();
```

My goal is to find a certain ID number in a database that will give me a passenger's information. If this ID is not in the database I want to use an if to write "ID not found" but I don't know how to do this. (I left it as NULL inside the if because I didn't know what to put in it so it won't be empty, so I can submit it here on Stack Overflow). What should I write inside the if to check if the ID exists?

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements with parameters. Do not concatenate values into a query string as that makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `identificacao` is a unique identifier, the query will return either one or no rows, so you don't need to process the result set with a `while`, but with an `if`:

```java
// Single row found
if (rs.next()) {
    int nidentificacaoP = rs.getInt("nidentificacao");
    String nome = rs.getString("nomeP");
    String sexo = rs.getString("sexo");
    String destinopretendido = rs.getString("destinopretendido");
    String dataviagem = rs.getString("dataviagem");
    System.out.println
        (nome + " do sexo "  + sexo + " para o destino " + 
         destinopretendido + " no dia " + dataviagem);
// No row found
} else {
    System.out.print("Identificacao nao encontrada");
}
```

**Mandatory side note:**
Concatenating the condition like that is at best a bad practice and at worst leaves your application vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks if `identificacao` is received from user-controlled input. You should probably convert this query to a [`PreparedStatemet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 3 errors/misconceptions in this code.

### SQL injection

> ```java
> String query = "SELECT nomeP, sexo, destinopretendido, dataviagem " +
>                    "FROM passageiros " +
>                    "WHERE nidentificacao='" + identificacao + "';";
> ```

Imagine the user types this on the command line:

`Whatever' OR 1 == 1; EXEC 'FORMAT C: /Y'; --`

That would mean the query matches many records (`OR 1 == 1` means it matches all of them), and it'll format your drive. This is called SQL injection; to avoid it, use `PreparedStatement` and **NEVER** put user input directly into the SQL. In general your SQL statements should be string literals.

### Selecting columns vs retrieving them

> ```java
> String query = "SELECT nomeP, sexo, destinopretendido, dataviagem " +
> ....
> rs.getInt("nidentificacao")
> ```

Your select statement states that you want 4 values to be returned for each matching row in the query. You then ask for the value of row 'nidentificacao' which isn't in there. The only 4 string values valid in `rs.getInt`, are `nomeP`, `sexo`, `destinopretendido` and `dataviagem`, because those are the only 4 columns in the query.

### Misunderstanding of how 'not found' is registered

Your query returns a number of rows. `while (rs.next())` loops once for each row. If `nidentificacao` is unique, given that you are looking for a specific value of it, your query returns either 1 row, or 0 rows.

If no row with `nidentificacao` at the searched-for value exists, you would get no rows. In your code, you assume you get a row, with `null` as value for `rs.getInt("nidentificacao");` which isn't how it works.

### `NULL` misconception

In SQL, `NULL` is a thing. In java, there's, at best, `null` (case sensitive). The various `.getX()` methods tend to return a placeholder value **and not `null`** for SQL NULL values. For example, if your SQL query returns `NULL` and you call `rs.getInt(column)` to retrieve it, you get 0, not `null` - that's because in java primitives cannot be `null`.

It isn't relevant here (checking for SQL NULL is *not* how you determine that no results are found; you determine that by realizing `rs.next()` will return `false` always - even the first time you call it) - but if it had been, that's not how its done.